# Why doesn't this PHP mail-function work?

Tags: php, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to get this php to work. I'm coding in visual studio 2012 (and have to do that because of my web-hotel). It seems that it can't manage php and I dont know what to do to get it work. I guess there are some kind of extensions that I need to download, but I can't get it work. I've tried to download phpTools, but when I'm installing it can't find visual studio 2012 (just 2015, not even when I'm uninstalling Visual studio 2015).

In the Bin-folder there are:

```
-Lang.Php.dll
-Lang.Php.pdb
-Lang.Php.Wp.dll
-Lang.Php.Wp.pdb

<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'yourname@yourdomain.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Is something wrong in the code? Because I didn't got it to work in Visual studio 2015 either - It said an end-tag was missing.

Comment: I formatted your code. Doesnt seem anything wrong with it in relation to the error message you are getting. Is this really the file the error is in?

Comment: Yes it is. Weird... Maybe it is because my Visual Studio can't read PHP properly?

Comment: did it say what type of end-tag was missing?

Comment: Not what I can remember. I've uninstalled that version of Visual studio så I can't see the message any more.